# How can I exporer the files at my Android device from Arch & Xfce?

Tags: arch-linux, xfce, android

In Ubuntu my Android gets mounted automatically when I plug it in it and it's very convient to explorer its files via the Ubuntu File Manager. In Arch my Android doesn't get seen by Arch, although I think I've installed all necessary libraries.

How can I do that in Arch with Xfce?

Whatever I install, it only mounts cdrom_install folder of Android at best which is even supposed to be for Windows support. Whereas I need to explorer its file system and usb card.

Comment: this ought to be useful. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/MTP

Comment: @Bibek_G, I've already read it.